# How to open new activity on button click inside TabLayout using Fragments

Tags: java, android

I wanted to create a app with Tabview so i started a app with Tabbed Activity with Action Bar tabs(with viewPager).Then i created fragment named tab1,tab2,tab3. You can find the tutorial that i followed to do above tabview in the following link and source code too

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/

from here my question starts in the above three tabs i created image view and a button up on clicking that button i wanted to open new activity.I am new to programming hope i will get answers. And i will be very grateful for the help.

Here is the code of the tab from here i wanted to call new activity on clicking a button.

`tab1.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#ca064006"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
            android:id="@+id/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Tab1.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Tab1 extends Fragment{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages, container, false);
    }
}
```

On clicking button in above code i want to call new activity can you please edit the code.

Comment: "on clicking that button i wanted to open new activity" -- call `startActivity()`  to start an activity. Using `startActivity()` is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html), along with any decent book or course on Android app development.

Comment: same activity or a different one ?.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information or clarify. Format the code. As a comment it's pretty much unreadable. Also note that comments may not be shown automatically. Make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Different Activity

Answer (score 0):

First you have to bind this button in you code, then use `Intent` to open another activity on the onClick event of that button

in the Fragment do the following:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages, container, false);

            Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID_IN_XML); //Binding the button view
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Do something in response to button click
                    Intent intent = new Intent (Tab1.this.getActivity(), OTHER-ACTIVITY-CLASS-NAME.class);
                    Tab1.this.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }
```

Comment: Atef Hares can you edit the code that i provide with the changes i requested for.

Comment: please provide more useful code, where is the code of the button!

Comment: I just updated the question please find it there and thanks for you reply and glad for you helping heart

Comment: @Kanna222 I saw you code and I see only an empty onCreateView method !! please provide more code

Comment: For your better understanding have a look at this link https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/  in tab1.xml code insted of textview showing ''tab1'' i created a button up on clicking that button i wanted to open a new different activity.

Comment: check the answer again now, and FYI you can not ask a question and ask readers to read some tutorial to help you! you have to be more specific

Comment: I am really sorry for that

Comment: I used your code and there are no errors and app is running well but when i click on that button the app crashes.Help please.and i feel sorry that i am bothering you.

Comment: please edit your question again and add the error log

Comment: At last its working i forgot to declare the new activity in android manifest thanks for your code and one more help when clicking the button new activity is opening but not in the fragment view but in full screen view.any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

I already posted an answer on a similar question, So to save time here was my answer:

I was facing the same issue and i easily solved it by calling my MainActivity viewpager from the firstFragment class, and then easily setting the viewpager's current item to the index of the tab you want.

here's the code which i placed in the onClick method of the first tab fragment for me to go the third tab fragment;

```
ViewPager viewPager = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.simpleViewPager);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
```

My answer might be late, but i hope it helps anyone else who might meet this challenge.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab, container, false);

            Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent (Tab1.this.getActivity(), //your_activity.class);
                    Tab1.this.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, explaining how it works would increase its long term value